# Laravel relationships not by ID's

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a couple of tables like so:

Authors Table
  - id
  - book_id
  - name

Books Table
  - id
  - ref
  - author
  - title

The ref on the books table is the same as the book_id on the authors table, but i can't seem to get the authors books by doing this in my view:

`{{ $author->books->first()->title }}`

My models for authors and books look like so:

```
class Authors extends \Eloquent {

protected $guarded = ['id'];

public $table = 'authors';

public $timestamps = false;

public function books()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Books', "author","name");
}

 }


 class Books extends \Eloquent {

protected $guarded = ['id'];

public $timestamps = false;

public function author()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Authors');
}

public function categories(){
    return $this->hasMany('Categories');
}

}
```

Really need some help on this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the foreign key and local key in `hasMany` but it looks like you're passing `author` as the foreign key and `name` as the local key. It should be `ref` for the foreign key and `book_id` for the local key.

```
class Authors extends \Eloquent {

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public $table = 'authors';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function books()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Books', "ref", "book_id");
    }

}


class Books extends \Eloquent {

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Authors');
    }

    public function categories(){
        return $this->hasMany('Categories');
    }

}
```

Comment: Legend thanks, I think i was getting myseld in a muddle, much appreciated.